# ##[error]No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the following demand: node.js

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am getting following error when I try to run my pipeline on self hosted agent (2.175.2)

```
##[error]No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the following demand: node.js. All demands: vstest, node.js, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1
```

The tasks in my pipeline are

```yaml
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  - task: PowerShell@2
  - task: CopyFiles@2
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  - task: AppCenterDistribute@3
  - task: VSTest@2
  - task: store-publish@0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the following demand: node.js.

From the error message, `node.js` is a necessary demand to run your pipeline. But it seems that the agents in the Default Agent Pool doesn't have this Capability.

You can navigate to `Organization Settings -> Agent Pools -> Default -> Target Agent -> Capabilities` to check the information.

[image]

Here are two methods to solve this issue:

- You could manually install node.js on the machine where the agent is installed. Then restart the build agent. Restarting the build agent will capture the added Capabilities.
- In Azure Devops Pipeline, you could add the task: `Node.js tool installer`

[image]

This task can install node.js in the agents of the Default agent pool.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant with node.js

```
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Installing Node.JS  
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '16.x'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).